# List<> in arguments for custom workflows?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I'm trying to have the following custom workflow retrieve `Contacts` based on the following criterias.

```
[Input("Retrieve customers whose renewal date is lesser or equal than today + X days")]
public InArgument<int> Days { get; set; }

[Input("For which service?")]
public InArgument<string> Service { get; set; }
```

And I'd want it to return the following:

```
[Output("Customers up for renewal")]
public OutArgument<List<Contact>> Customers{ get; set; }
```

My idea is that another workflow step will loop through what this workflow returns (`Customers`).

But when I'm registering the assembly, the step above fails to register due to:

```
The type OutArgument`1 of the property Customers is not supported
```

What type of arguments are supported then ? MSDN did not tell me much and is my concept of returning a list faulty or can a workflow process only one record at a time ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom Workflow Activities can use as `OutArgument` only a set of types, and there isn't a type (like an `EntityCollection` for example) to return multiple items as a single `OutArgument`.

Because you want to return a list of `Contact` you can use a static Marketing List as workaround.

Inside your Custom Workflow Activity you create a new Marketing List and put the contacts as members of the list (Marketing List can be used only with contacts, accounts or leads) and return the Id of the list as an `EntityReference`:

```
[Output("List of Contacts")]
[ReferenceTarget("list")]
public OutArgument<EntityReference> MarketingListRef { get; set; }


// code to create the marketing list and add the contacts
Guid marketingListId;

// set the OutArgument
EntityReference marketingListRef = new EntityReference("list",marketingListId);
MarketingListRef.Set(executionContext, marketingListRef);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the list of supported types for attributes [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327984.aspx). I think I will have to restructure my workflow so it internally deals with the list of `Customers` as this list won't be something you can expose to another workflow step.

Comment: you can return a new static marketing list containing the contacts. Maybe not optimal without knowing your entire situation but does the job

Comment: @GuidoPreite Could you elaborate in an answer perhaps ? I can't see this type in the MSDN link I posted above. Thanks.